# Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE (C++ getting PHP sockets)

Tags: php, c++, sockets, tcp, access-violation

I've basically got some code in PHP that simply connects to my C++ server that's listening on a port, sends a message, and then closes the socket.

I'm trying to read what I'm sending but the thing is....if I connect too many times the C++ server eventually spews out an exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00B6C99B in Server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.

Basically on page load in the PHP script it connects the socket (TCP) to the C++ server, sends a message, and then closes the socket. So if I hold down refresh by the time it's done this about 34 times (number varies) I get an exception.

In the stack I can see that some variables have: "udp=??? format=???", which is extremely weird because these are all ready defined, no idea why there's a question mark.

And also the data I send from PHP is:

```
$message = "hello";
```

And in the locals in Visual Studio the data turns out to be:

> "helloð­º\rð­º\rð­º\rð­º\rð­º\rð­ºîþ««««««««îþ"

Some other variables have "Error reading characters of string"
while others have:
"Unable to read memory"

Here's my code:

```
double webListen = tcplisten(cst::WEB_PORT, 100, 1);
setnagle(webListen, true);

std::list<double> webUsers;

if (webListen <= 0) {
    cout << "Failed to listen on port " << cst::WEB_PORT <<endl;
}
cout << endl << "Server listening on port " << cst::WEB_PORT << endl;

while(1){
    double WebUser = tcpaccept(webListen, 1);
    if(WebUser > -1){
        cout<< "NEW WEB: " << WebUser <<  endl;
        webUsers.push_back(WebUser);
    }
    std::list<double>::iterator it = webUsers.begin();
    while (it != webUsers.end())
    {
        cout << "SOCK: " << *it << endl;
        //USE A TRY CATCH!!!
        //try{
        double Size = receivemessage(*it, 1024, 2); // Messages coming from web users (whether it be from website or someone using api)
        if(Size == -1){

        }
        else if(Size == 0){
            cout << "WEB GONE: " << *it << endl;
            webUsers.erase(it++);
        }
        else if(Size > 0){
            cout << "SIZE: " << Size << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

The exception happens when it tries to access the UDP variable in this function:

```
    int CSocket::receivemessage(int len, CBuffer*destination)
{
    if(sockid<0)return -1;
    int size = -1;
    char* buff = NULL;

    if(udp)
    {
        size = 8195;
        buff = new char[size];
        size = recvfrom(sockid, buff, size, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);
    } else
    {
        if(format == 0 && !len)
        {
            unsigned short length;
            if(recv(sockid, (char*)&length, 2, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)return -1;
            buff = new char[length];
            size = recv(sockid, buff, length, 0);
        } else if(format == 1 && !len)
        {
            size = 65536;
            buff = new char[size];
            size = receivetext(buff, size);
        } else if(format == 2 || len > 0)
        {
            buff = new char[len];
            size = recv(sockid, buff, len, 0);
        }
    }
    if(size > 0)
    {
        destination->clear();
        destination->addBuffer(buff, size);
    }
    if(buff != NULL)delete buff;
    return size;
}
```

But I mean variables such as udp and format are all ready defined...
Is it the CSocket object that could be corrupt?
I mean why is it that this only happens after refreshing the PHP page so many times?
What makes it corrupt like this?

Comment: Wrong form of `delete` is used here:  `if(buff != NULL)delete buff`  It should be `delete[]`.  Also, there is no need to check for NULL when issuing a call to `delete`.  Finally, use `std::vector<char>` instead of `new[]/delete[]`

Comment: `webUsers.erase(it++);`  That `it` iterator has become invalidated, but you're incrementing it.  That doesn't look right.

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm still getting the access exception. I changed "webUsers.erase(it++)" to: "it = webUsers.erase(it)" and I changed the function to use an std::vector<char>. Here's my new receivemessage() function: [link](http://pastebin.com/KbV6Q7zQ)